# Twice clicking is needed to open dropdown menu in IE, working fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, drupal-7

I am working with a Drupal 7 site and facing a problem in IE.
For the menu items to open twice clicking is needed (only in IE).
In Chrome, it is opening in one click as needed.

Here is the link of the site: http://gwccgtclone626.bitnamiapp.com
You can try opening it in both IE and Chrome.
Then try to open any menu (e.g. Applications) by clicking on it.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the navigation links from the top level menus.
eg.

change

```
<a class="active-trail dropdown-toggle disabled" href="/our-alternator-brands">Products<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
```

to

```
<a class="active-trail dropdown-toggle disabled" href="#">Products<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
```

The common design pattern for dropdown menus is to expand the child UL on click or hover.. IE is bubbling the click event.

Regards.

Comment: But while clicking on the dropdown menu, the link needs to open